# In dihedral group $FR=R^{-1}F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, dihedral-groups

Let F be any reflection (flip ) about axis of symmetry .
And R be rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{n} $ radian counterclockwise .(n is the number of vertex).

Then $FR=R^{-1}F$

I looked at some example  and it works .But how can we prove this thing rigorously ( I need this in proving subgroup -set of all rotation is normal )

I have no idea on proving this rigorously. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $F$ is a reflection and $R$ is a rotation, so $FR$ is a reflection and note that any reflection has order $2$.

Now

$(FR)^2=e$ implies $FRFR=e=R^{-1}R$ , cancellation gives $$FRF=R^{-1}=R^{-1}.e=R^{-1}(F^{-1}F)$$ and again by cancellation  $$FR=R^{-1}F^{-1}=R^{-1}F$$

Comment: So FR is a flip? But how do we know it is a flip

Comment: Also good to see you are from tn. Me too sir

Comment: Yes! There is a good idea to remember these products! namely assign $-1$ to reflections and $+1$ to rotations. Then $1 \times 1=1$ means rotation X rotation=rotation and  $-1 \times 1=-1$ means ref X rot =ref and so on

Comment: For a sake of simplicity, work in $D_3$, the group of symmetrices on a triangle. See [this](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math330/d3.pdf) paper. It is really useful(I hope)

Comment: I glad to see you! Don't saying 'sir'. Because I'm not an instructor! Of course I'm not a student also!  Are you a student? If so, in which college of Tamil nadu?

Comment: read chapter 1 of Gallian's contemporary abstract algebra. Gallian explains these  details in a geometrical way!  If you have any doubt about this, ask here. Now I'm  going  to sleep! bye!

Comment: I studied in gallain and in 9 th chapter i had this doubt btw I'm studying in thiagarajar clg but studied to get in TIFR or CMI .its really difficult for me to study own coz i have only very few instructor also they are too busy in administration work...In my college they follow book by 'arumugam ' which is a garbage in my point.so i need to study seperatly and mathstack exchange is only place where i could find people helping me to study...n thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84203/discussion-between-cloud-jr-and-chinnapparaj-r).

Comment: Actually Arumugam sir book is a prerequisite for algebra. Ok! first study Gallian and solve the exercise problems and then move  on to Artin or Herstein if you wish. For competitive  exam point of view, solve as many problems as you can. Don't expect the answer for the particular problem in one sitting. But the big challenging is keeping up!  So study regularly and if you stuck on any problem, ask here. We are glad to help you! bye!